# QImage, difference between color and intensity

Tags: qt, qimage

In Qt I have class QImage in which I have method  setColorTable, so and I can't understand differences between ColorTable and QImage.pixel(x,y). So the second is intensity, am I right?

Comment: The second (`pixel(x,y)`) will return color. If the image is indexed image, the color will be retrieved from `ColorTable`. If you want the index, use `pixelIndex(x,y)`.

Comment: So I need to get intensity.

Comment: Then use `pixelIndex(x,y)`. But the image format must be `Mono, Mono_LSB, Indexed8`. What is your image type? If it's a color image, you need to convert it to grayscale (using `qGray(QRgb)`). If the image is grayscale, then `pixel(x,y)` will return color in which all the `RGB` component is the same. You can get the intensity from one of R/G/B channel.

Comment: I have already figured this out, but anyway thank you. Because i check out that i'm right by your answer.